# How to use one observable values in another?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have an android app, that fetches 2 data types from network, one for channel list, and the other for epg's

The point is, my epg url must contain the channel id's from the channels list. Here's what i'm trying to do

```
Observable<ChannelList> channelList =
        NetworkService.getChannels();

List<String> channelIds = new ArrayList<>();

channelList.subscribe(chList -> {
            for (ChannelInfo chInfo : chList.getChannelInfoList()) {
                channelIds.add(chInfo.getId());
            }
        });

Observable<EpgList> epgList =
        NetworkService.getEpgList(channelIds);
```

but it doesn't fetch the id's until the method is done, so how do i block the execution at that point and require the id's?

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: yeah, but i have another problem here :) i want to zip them later into one observable, so i'll be able to pass the data to an adapter, and there the problem begins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NetworkService.getChannels()
                        .map(chList -> chList.getChannelInfoList())
                        .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
                        .map(channelInfo -> channelInfo.getId())
                        .toList()
                        .switchMap(channelIds -> NetworkService.getEpgList(channelIds))
                        .subscribe(epgList -> Timber.d("%s", epgList));
```